# Extract paragraphs in web Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, artificial-intelligence

I am going to scrape news articles from the web sites. How can I scrape paragraphs from the periculer web article? How can I loop through the `<p>` tags? This is my code

```
diepresse_url='https://www.diepresse.com/'
html = requests.get(diepresse_url)
bsobj = soup(html.content, 'lxml')
links = []

for link in bsobj.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^https://www.diepresse.com/6")}):
  link = link.get('href')
  links.append(link)

lst2 = []
for l in links:
   page = requests.get(l)
   b = soup(page.content)

      
   lstA =[]
   for data in b.find_all("p", {'id' :'absatz1'}): 
     lstA.append(data.get_text())
     q = ' '.join(lstA)[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ54Y.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ54Y.jpg)
     lst2.append(q)
```

I tried to loop through the `<p>` tags, but it failed because length of the links list and paragraph lists were different.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to organize the articles and paragraphs and this should work for large lists of links

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup



def get_tag(link,tag="p"):
    page = requests.get(link)
    b = soup(page.content,features='html.parser')
    lst2=[]
    for data in b.find_all(tag): 
        text=data.get_text().replace("\n","")
        while "  " in text:
            text=text.replace("  "," ")
        if text.startswith(" "):
            text=text[1:len(text)]
        if text.endswith(" "):
            text=text[0:len(text)-1]
        lst2.append(text)
    return lst2

class article_paragraphs:
    def __init__(self,link):
        self.link=link
        self.paragraphs=self.get_paragraphs_from_link()
        self.indexed_paragraphs=self.get_paragraphs_from_link()
        self.current_index=0
    def index_paragraphs_by_prefix(self,prefix):
        para={}
        for i,p in enumerate(self.paragraphs,start=0):
            para[f"{prefix}{i}"]=p
        self.indexed_paragraphs=para
        
    def index_paragraphs_by_name(self,*names):
        para={}
        for i,p in enumerate(self.paragraphs,start=0):
            para[str(names[i])]=p
        self.indexed_paragraphs=para
        
    def current_paragraph(self):
        return self.paragraphs[self.current_index]
    
    def next_paragraph(self):
        self.current_index+=1
        if self.current_index>len(self.paragraphs):
            self.current_index=0
    def previous_paragraph(self):
        self.current_index-=1
        if self.current_index<0:
            self.current_index=len(self.paragraphs)
            
    def set_paragraph(self,index):
        self.current_index=index
        if index>len(self.paragraphs):
            index=len(self.paragraphs)
        if index<0:
            index=0
        
    def get_paragraphs_from_link(self):
        return get_tag(self.link)
  

class articles:
    def __init__(self,links):
        self.articles=self.get_articles_from_link(links)
        self.indexed_articles=self.articles
        self.current_index=0
        
    def index_articles_by_prefix(self,prefix):
        para={}
        for i,p in enumerate(self.articles,start=0):
            para[f"{prefix}{i}"]=p
        self.indexed_articles=para
        
    def index_articles_by_name(self,*names):
        para={}
        for i,p in enumerate(self.articles,start=0):
            para[str(names[i])]=p
        self.indexed_articles=para
        
    def current_article(self):
        return self.articles[self.current_index]
    
    def next_article(self):
        self.current_index+=1
        if self.current_index>len(self.articles):
            self.current_index=0
    def previous_article(self):
        self.current_index-=1
        if self.current_index<0:
            self.current_index=len(self.articles)
            
    def set_article(self,index):
        self.current_index=index
        if index>len(self.articles):
            index=len(self.articles)
        if index<0:
            index=0
        
    def get_articles_from_link(self,links):
        return [article_paragraphs(l) for l in links]
```